# Cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: cinnamon

Any word on when Cinnamon may be updated for Ubuntu 14.04? I know it takes time, so I hope no one thinks I am being an impatient little brat, just curious.

Thanks all!

Comment: nobody knows except the PPA owner.

Answer (score 0):

See this post which explains how to update 14.04 to latest Cinnamon: http://linuxg.net/cinnamon-2-2-has-been-released-how-to-install-cinnamon-2-2-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

Answer (score 0):

The pairs versions of cinnamon are stable, then the cinnamon 2.2 must be updated, but  cinnamon 2.3 should not be updated. Usually the release of the firsts cinnamon pairs versions are for error correction, as 2.2.1 - 2.2.5 from 2.2.5 onwards can expect an update at any time, which depends of the author of the ppa.